# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://localhost:3306/twitch

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was trying to connect to MySQL "twitch" database using java with this code below:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            String url = "jdbc://localhost:3306/twitch";
            String username = "root";
            String pass = "nfreal-yt10";

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pass);
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select distinct creator_id from twitch.information where creator_id > 40;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

when I executed the code my console throws (Full error):

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. 
This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver 
class is generally unnecessary.        
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://localhost:3306/twitch
```

I have added MySQL connector on my directory folder and all stuff which required to be added, yet the error still occurred, why?

Comment: Do not use that `Class.forName( <JDBCDriverClass> )` for up-to-date JDBC drivers! The class will be detected automatically when the driver Jar is on the CLASSPATH (if it is not on the CLASSPATH, also that explicit reference will not help). And to solve the issue in general, see the answer from @Zerak

Comment: You have a typo in your URL, it should start with `jdbc:mysql:`, not just with `jdbc:`.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you communicate with your database (located at **/localhost:3306/twitch**), you must precise the protocol used (eg. your browser use *http* or *https* protocol followed with the adress).

JDBC is a driver that can interface with MySQL, but can't directly access to your database. Hence your URL should be:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twitch";
```

EDIT : `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` is no more needed **in general**. Details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Comment: Wait, what do you mean 'which kind of database JDBC should communicate'? what should I add on my URL?, I'm a novice when it comes to database stuff

Comment: PS He should use neither. The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006.

Comment: @user207421 – Right, but not for all JDBC driver implementations (although for all the big ones, including MySQL as used here). Just recently I stumbled into a JDBC implementation where the `Class::forName` was still required. But as said: in *general*, you are right! There just are still some exotic exceptions …

Comment: @STACKOVERFLOWUSER – The string between the first and the second colon determines the type of the JDBC implementation to use – here it is "mysql", as Zerak wrote. That part is missing from the URL that you used in your code.

Comment: @tquadrat  What JDBC implementation was that? and what JDBC version does it claim to be compliant with? JDBC 4.0, 2006, *required* this.

Comment: @user207421 – It was an implementation for a non-standard database in a customer environment, and it implemented something half way between JDBC 1.0 and JDBC 2.0. But the detection mechanism is just implemented through `ServiceLoader` – if there is a `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file, the `Class::forName` is obsolete (or if it is missing, you need to have that call). JDBC 4.0 just added this as a requirement, but does not really force it …

Comment: @tquadrat I'm sure you will find that the JDBC TCK (compatilbility test suite) does require it. The issue you had was a pre-JDBC 4.0 driver.